# Training in batch does not converge while training samples individually does

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning Tensorflow and trying some test models to get the feeling how Tensorflow works. The model is pretty simple (a linear model) and it has the following input and output:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="Input")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="Output")
```

So basically, the input and output have one single dimension. As for training phase:

```
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
  for (x, y) in zip(trX, trY):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: [x], Y: [y]})
```

The above code is when I train the model one single sample at a time and it works. As for my next step, I wanted to see how I can train the model with the whole set at each epoch:

```
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
  sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})
```

Training this way does not converge. And `trX` & `trY` are both of shape `(101, 1)`. So is my expectation not in place or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was in the cost function definition. Originally, the cost function was defined like this:

```
cost = tf.pow(Y - y_model, 2)
```

I realized it's missing the average component (the previous one is returning a matrix instead of a single value).

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(Y - y_model, 2))
```